# print automatically pdf file with powershell

Tags: pdf, powershell, printing

I'm printing a pdf file with:

```
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\file.pdf" –Verb Print
```

This opens an empty adobe reader window, prints the file, but keeps the adobe reader open. So, how do I close adobe reader?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6):

From [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/acrobat_sdk/10/Acrobat10_HTMLHelp/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=Acrobat10_SDK_HTMLHelp&file=DevFAQ_UnderstandingSDK.22.31.html) seems like that is how AcroRd32 will work - it will keep the Adobe Reader open and you can only control whether it is minimized when it starts or not.

One alternative is to use Foxit Reader as described here- http://www.deltasblog.co.uk/code-snippets/printing-pdf-files-from-command-line-without-adobe-reader/

Or,Hack:

```
Start-Process -FilePath "test.pdf" –Verb Print
sleep 10
kill -name AcroRd32
```

Updated hack for multiple Adobe readers open:

```
Start-Process -FilePath "test.pdf" –Verb Print -PassThru | %{sleep 10;$_} | kill
```

Comment: Thank you for the help manojlds. I thought of doing that, but if I have another pdf file open couldn't it kill it too? I could use foxit reader as a standalone executable so I would be almost sure nobody else would use it.

Comment: @Arthur Carvalho - Updated the hack so that already open file won't close. Still a hack :)